# When you have more than one multi-value drop downs, is there a way to use one or the other?

Tags: reporting-services

When you have more than one multi-value drop down, is there a way to use one or the other?

Right now, with my logic I've added a drop down parameter. This drop down has the following values:

- **Return Everything - 1** - (This should default both multi-value drop downs to "Everything"
- **Select Param 1 - 2** - (This should allow you to choose whatever you want from parameter 1, and default parameter 2 to "Everything")
- **Select Param 2 - 3** - (This should allow you to choose whatever you want from parameter 2, and default parameter 1 to "Everything")

To handle this, I use the following expressions in the default vaules of the parameters:

**Parameter 1** (zero is a value returned in the parameter):

```
=iif(Parameters!Criteria.Value = 1, Nothing, iif(Parameters!Criteria.Value = 3, Nothing, 0))
```

And **Parameter 2**:

```
=iif(Parameters!Criteria.Value = 1, Nothing, iif(Parameters!Criteria.Value = 2, Nothing, 0))
```

However, this logic does not seem to be working as I'd expect. The expression `Nothing` should throw a `NULL` into my parameter dataset, there in turn defaulting to return "Everything", however this is not happening.

Comment: Where have you put those expressions (for Parameter 1 / 2)?

Comment: In the default vaules of the parameters I want to choose from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would modify the approach - AFAIK you can only use an Expression to set a single value as a default.

So, I would create a new dataset each for Parameter1 and Parameter2. This dataset will provide the default values for each Parameter (in place of the expression you are currently attempting).

E.g. the new Parameter1_Default dataset should present all the rows normally presented to Parameter 1.  Then in the WHERE clause for this dataset, add: WHERE 3 = @Criteria.

Then in the Parameter1 definition, set the Default Values to come from the new Parameter1_Default dataset.  When Criteria = 3 it will "Select All" the Parameter1 values.  When Criteria <> 3 no Parameter1 values will be selected.

Repeat for Parameter2.

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm.  It is unfortunate to have (in my case) multiple stored procs for both parameters but I'll take it!